# XCode 13 - generating Localizable.strings file for development langauge (English in my case), without using genstrings

Tags: xcode, localization

I wanted to know how to generate the English base case Localizable.strings file in Xcode 13 without using genstrings.

I'm using the new compiler support to extract strings for localisation then **exporting** -> **translating** -> **importing** via the `.xcloc` files. All this works nicely, aside from one problem...

I'm having difficulty getting it to create the initial Localizable.strings file in the development language, i.e. `en` in my case. When I try and import the relevant `en.xcloc` file nothing happens. I can import other languages without problem.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. Write some basic code with one piece of text that can be localised
2. Select **Product -> Export Localisations...** and choose **English - Development Language**

Correctly creates `en.xcloc` file - contents as expected, picking up the text to be localised.

3. Select **Product -> Import Localisations...** and re-import the english `en.xcloc` file

This does nothing. So I try the following:

4. Go to **Project**'s file -> **Info tab** and add a new language, say (Fr)
5. Select **Product -> Export Localisations...** and choose `English - Development Language` and `French` options
6. Open `fr.xcloc` file and add translations required
7. Come back to Xcode and import `fr.xcloc` file
8. Now the `Localizable.strings` file appears - it is of course the French version
9. Importing the `en.xcloc` file still does nothing
10. If I open up the file inspector on the right, I can click to add an English version, but it simply copies the French version (which causes lots of other issues)...

I think where I'm coming from, is that because one doesn't have to rely on genstrings in Xcode 13, I'm wondering how to create the initial translation files.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode only creates a `Localizable.strings` file when importing the `en.xcloc` file, assuming this is your development language, if you go into the exported `en.xcloc` file and change one of the *translations*. Then when  import the updated file a `Localizable.strings` file will appear for `en`, yet only containing the changes you have made, rather than entries for all the keys.